# Solr slow indexing at /update/json/docs

Tags: json, docker, api, solr

Solr Detail :
Solr Version : 9.2.0
Environtment : Docker with ubuntu 22.04 host (Local)

Api Test using Postman & Golang http package

So i have question, i am trying to send indexing data to this link : `http://localhost:8983/solr/kms_article/update/json/docs` it takes a long time. i tried a lot of time and my indexing request is taking a long time. do mind that i only send 1 small text, it shouldnt take more than a minute but i wait more than 10 minutes and nothing happening. hoping to find some explanation and some fix. Thanks!

when i do post request to this link :
`http://localhost:8983/solr/kms_article/update/json/docs`

and then send json data like this

```json
{
    "ArticleID": "4asdaasdasasdasdasddsd",
    "OwnerID": 10,
    "OwnerUsername": "asdbvxccccccccccvcxbcvbcxvbc",
    "OwnerName": "asdas",
    "LastEditedByID": 5,
    "LastEditedByUsername": "asdasd",
    "LastEditedByName": "asdasd",
    "LastEditedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Tag": [
        "a",
        "b"
    ],
    "Title": "sadasd",
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "CategoryName": "asdasd",
    "CategoryParent": "asdasd",
    "CategoryDescription": "asdasd",
    "Article": "asdsad",
    "FileID": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "DocID": [
        3,
        4
    ],
    "IsActive": 5,
    "DocContent": "asdasdasd"
}
```

The indexing process takes a long time, only some success. and those success attempt only happen when i restart my solr docker env or i do another update using Solr Admin UI

at the same time, when i do this request to this link
`http://localhost:8983/solr/kms_article/update?commitWithin=1000&overwrite=true&wt=json`

with the json data above but i add "[" at the start and "]" at the end. and suddenly the process is really quick. i was really confused, here is my solr core if maybe my setting is kinda wrong https://github.com/SMAMHTN/test_solr

Thanks!